# Will I Have a Problem Upgrading from Flash Player 9 to Flash Player 10 for my Flex 3 Site?

Tags: apache-flex, flash

I've got a Flex 3 project that targets Flash Player 9. Should I upgrade to target Flash Player 10?

Will I have problems if I do so? Can I simply change which version I target in preferences, or is it more complicated than that?

-Laxmidi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to force an upgrade; but you can if you want to.

Anything you write in Flex that works on Flash Player 9 should work fine in Flash Player 10.

Comment: Hi Flextras,

I guess that I'll keep using Flash Player 9 then. 

Thanks!